# Adding files to a Netbeans C++ project

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, makefile, notepad++

### Background

I was working on a C++ project on a Windows machine, building using a makefile, and editing with Notepad++. I then decided to switch to a modern IDE, partly so that I wouldn't have to keep editing the makefile, so I installed Netbeans (first time I have used this IDE). When I created the project, I specified my existing makefile. All is well, and I can edit and build my project.

There were a couple of source files in the directory which were not mentioned in the makefile. However, they do show up in the file list in grey:

[image: Netbeans file list greyed out]

### Problem

I can't for the life of me figure out how to add those grey files to the build. Do I *still* have to edit the makefile? Isn't the IDE supposed to manage this kind of thing?

Comment: Netbeans is a poor C++ IDE. If you are working on Windows, check out Visual Studio, Code::Blocks and CLion.

Comment: @latedeveloper - Actually I'm doing remote compilation on a Linux machine. Can you do that with VS Express?

Comment: @Rocket "I'm doing remote compilation on a Linux machine" Why? Your post said you were working on Windows, and my comment was predicated on that.

Comment: @Captain Shall we say that your experiences with NetBeans and mine differ markedly, and leave it at that? It's software I've always wanted to like, but can't.

Comment: @latedeveloper - sorry. I originally mentioned the remote compilation, but I thought the question was getting too wordy, and that seemed like a distraction that wasn't absolutely necessary, so I deleted that bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Netbeans won't change your custom Makefile.  If I were in your shoes, I'd start a new project and add the source files manually, and after that write any custom build steps you might require.